"The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files" ERROR for Spring Boot Application
I am on Eclipse IDE, and I am getting this red mark on the line where I have my package written. I created this with the Spring Initializer. I just wanted to check if Spring works, but then it'd show an exception...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:  String cannot be resolved to a type  at com.thisPebbleCodes.carDealership.CarDealershipApplication.main(CarDealershipApplication.java:9) 
package com.thisPebbleCodes.carDealership;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CarDealershipApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      SpringApplication.run(CarDealershipApplication.class, args);
    }

}

I tried:

Cleaning the project
Deleting and re-importing the project
I removed and added jdk 22 back again under the Modulepath in Java build path.


Is your Eclipse up to date? Did you configured the Java 22 JDK in the preferences Java > Installed JREs? Please tell the exact error message that is shown in the Problems view.

@howlger you were right. I have not been checking for updates. I just updated, and now it works! Thank you! ^^
